# XPath - Table rows that do not contain table headers in them

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm using a WebRequest in C# to download a webpage's HTML and using XPath with HtmlAgilityPack to select the nodes I want. I have noticed that the WebRequest returns a table without the  and  specifiers (I'm guessing those are injected via Javascript after the page loads?)

Anyways, the table is downloaded as just a  tag with  tags inside. However, the first row is the header, and I want to skip that. Is there a way in xpath to select all  tags inside of the  tag that do not have any  descendants?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//tr[not(th)]
```

will select all `tr` elements that have no `th` child elements.